# What account controls Ethereum contract?

Tags: ethereum, smartcontracts

I am currently following this tutorial: https://medium.com/@mvmurthy/full-stack-hello-world-voting-ethereum-dapp-tutorial-part-2-30b3d335aa1f

The way I deployed the contract was by using **truffle migrate** command which presumably automatically pushes it to the newtwork from a certain account which I should have created earlier using **web3** library, specifically **web3.personal.newAccount('*some_password*')**.

Considerring I have created multiple accounts, which one owns the contract i.e. what account gets ether taken from?
(is it the latest I have created)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't set the default account in your Truffle config, it will use the first account returned from `web3.eth.getAccounts()`.

From the [Truffle docs](http://truffleframework.com/docs/advanced/configuration#networks):

> - gas: Gas limit used for deploys. Default is 4712388.
> - gasPrice: Gas price used for deploys. Default is 100000000000 (100 Shannon).
> - from: From address used during migrations. **Defaults to the first available account provided by your Ethereum client.**
> - provider: Default web3 provider using host and port options: new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://:")

To specify the default address, add `from` to the network environment configuration.

Example truffle.js:

```
module.exports = {
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: "localhost",
      port: 8545,
      network_id: "*",
      from: "0x65463bf6268e5cc409b6501ec846487b935a1446"
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Truffle. You can specify an account from the from.You can check this document
   http://truffleframework.com/docs/advanced/configuration
2. You need unlock this account.